# Calculating when there is minimum/maximum distances between Earth and Venus with skyfield

Tags: python

I have been trying to compute the times and dates for when Venus is at it's closest and furthest position away from earth, but I keep getting a ValueError.

This is my code so far:
I think i am not using the zip(*,*) function properly, however any suggestions are much appreciated. Thanks.

```
from skyfield.api import load
from skyfield.framelib import ecliptic_frame
from skyfield.searchlib import find_maxima
from skyfield.searchlib import find_minima

ts = load.timescale()
i = 2000

def distance_at(t):
   
    ra, dec, distance = position.radec()
    return distance  


while i < 2024:
    t0 = ts.utc(i)
    t1 = ts.utc(i+1)

    eph = load('de421.bsp')
    sun, earth, venus = eph['sun'], eph['earth'], eph['venus']

    earth_d, planet_d = eph['earth'], eph['venus']


    distance_at.step_days = 15.0

    times, distance = find_maxima(t0, t1, distance_at)

    for t, distance in zip(times, distance):

        print('{} min distance is: {}'.format(
            t.utc_strftime(), distance))
    
    i = i + 1
```

Comment: What error do you get? Please give us a full error text with traceback, it will show where the problem is exactly.

Answer (score 1):

```
def distance_at(t):
   
    ra, dec, distance = position.radec()
    return distance
```

- you are not using t parameter anywhere in function
- position is not defined
- parameter distance_at not defined. Also there is a function in same name. I am confused.

These are my ideas.